# Does power bi allow reports to be scraped?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, powerbi

I want to scrape some text out of power bi reports that are published in my workspace server using scrapy.
Does power bi allow scraping? 
Can someone point me to resources to get started? 
I found a lot of online resources that are around doing scraping in power bi using power query and python but didn't find much on the topic I wanted.
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: in the first place why you want to scrape data? If you need some just ask your data owner/report designer

Comment: sorry I can't share more details on the use case but please add your inputs to the original question if possible Thanks!